# Solving System of Differential Equations and Plotting

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm struggling with this exercise of Initial Value Problem:
Two equations with conditions

- $x_1$'=-2$x_1$-3$x_2$+cos(5t)
- $x_2$'=-$x_1$-5$x_2$+sin(10t)
- $x_1$(0)=1
- $x_2$(0)=-1

Then i need to build the graph of R(t)=  √($x_1$^2+$x_2$^2)
For 0≤t≤10
So far I have this code, but the graph is appearing empty.

```
solution = NDSolve[
  {x1'[t] == -2 x1[t] - 3 x2[t] + Cos[5 t],
   x2'[t] == -x1[t] - 5 x2[t] + Sin[10 t],
   x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == -1},
  {x1, x2},
  {t, 0, 10}
  ]
X = x1[t] /. solution[[1, 1]];
Y = x2[t] /. solution[[1, 2]];
z[t_] := Sqrt[X[t]^2 + Y[t]^2];
Plot[z[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Use `Plot[Evaluate[Sqrt[x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2] /. solution], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: `X = x1 /. solution[[1, 1]];Y = x2 /. solution[[1, 2]];` will fix your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

Starting at around $t=10.25$, the solution calculated with `NDSolve[]` starts to blow up:

```
 Plot[Evaluate[Sqrt[x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2] /. solution], {t, 0, 10.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

(Thank you @Alex Trounev for clarification on how to plot this with `Evaluate`)

[image]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 10.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 10.5}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}]
```

[image]

Better to use `DSolve[]`:

```
solution = 
 DSolve[{x1'[t] == -2 x1[t] - 3 x2[t] + Cos[5 t], 
   x2'[t] == -x1[t] - 5 x2[t] + Sin[10 t], x1[0] == 1, 
   x2[0] == -1}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}]

 Plot[Evaluate[Sqrt[x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2] /. solution], {t, 0, 24.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
 Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 25}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: If you put  the same upper limit of  `t` in both the `DSolve` and the `Plot` lines of code (for example 12), you will not see a steep increase after 10.5...If these limits are not the same I doubt your solution  is mathematically.correct.

Comment: This is true for `NDSolve`, but I don't think for DSolve. Since `DSolve` finds the exact solution, it does not depend on the range of $t$ (unless, there are multiple solutions in different regions). Nevertheless, you are right, if you ask for `NDSolve` in a certain range, that's all you get. Going further in $t$ it will extrapolate, causing the large errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {x1'[t] == -2 x1[t] - 3 x2[t] + Cos[5 t], 
   x2'[t] == -x1[t] - 5 x2[t] + Sin[10 t], x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == -1};

solution = NDSolve[eqns, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 10}];
X = x1[t] /. solution[[1, 1]];
Y = x2[t] /. solution[[1, 2]];
```

As defined, `X` and `Y` are implicit functions of `t` they do not take `t` as an explicit argument

```
z[t_] := Sqrt[X^2 + Y^2];

Plot[z[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) will provide an exact solution

```
solExact = DSolve[eqns, {x1, x2}, t][[1]];
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eqns /. solExact // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)

$Assumptions = t >= 0;

z[t_] = Norm[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. solExact // Simplify] // Simplify

(* (1/41974802)E^(-Sqrt[
   21] t) \[Sqrt]((19573853 E^(1/2 (-7 + Sqrt[21]) t) + 
      938127 Sqrt[21] E^(1/2 (-7 + Sqrt[21]) t) + 
      19573853 E^(1/2 (-7 + 3 Sqrt[21]) t) - 
      938127 Sqrt[21] E^(1/2 (-7 + 3 Sqrt[21]) t) - 
      487764 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Cos[5 t] + 3314860 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Cos[10 t] + 
      948430 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Sin[5 t] - 1592372 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Sin[10 t])^2 + 
    4 (9755223 E^(1/2 (-7 + Sqrt[21]) t) - 
       4189868 Sqrt[21] E^(1/2 (-7 + Sqrt[21]) t) + 
       9755223 E^(1/2 (-7 + 3 Sqrt[21]) t) + 
       4189868 Sqrt[21] E^(1/2 (-7 + 3 Sqrt[21]) t) + 
       1151665 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Cos[5 t] + 325290 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Cos[10 t] + 
       3590485 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Sin[5 t] + 432171 E^(Sqrt[21] t) Sin[10 t])^2) *)

Plot[z[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach using `NDSolveValue`:

```
{X, Y, z[t_]} = 
  NDSolveValue[{x1'[t] == -2 x1[t] - 3 x2[t] + Cos[5 t], 
    x2'[t] == -x1[t] - 5 x2[t] + Sin[10 t], x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == -1},
   {x1, x2, Sqrt[x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2]}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[z[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]